# Windows Auth shared across multiple .net core applications

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, iis, .net-core

I currently have two .net core 3.1 applications being hosted on an IIS server with distinct app pools. Both are using windows authentication and not allowing anonymous auth. I am trying to make it so that signing into application A will not prompt a log in for application B. Initially I started looking into using a shared cookie / using identity but after some digging it seems like this isn't the recommended when using windows auth? My startup ConfigureServices looks as such:

```
            services.AddAuthentication(IISDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
            services.AddSingleton<IClaimsTransformation, ClaimsTransformer>();
            services.AddAutoMapper(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
            services.AddControllersWithViews();
            services.AddSpaStaticFiles(configuration =>
            {
                configuration.RootPath = "ClientApp/dist";
            });
```

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

> Initially I started looking into using a shared cookie / using identity but after some digging it seems like this isn't the recommended when using windows auth?

Yes, if you used windows authentication in IIS, it will contain two authentication way,  Kerberos or NTLM, both of them is happened at http.sys not inside the asp.net core application. So ,you couldn't do it in asp.net core application.

Normally, if you want to avoid showing the prompt for the user, you should make sure the client is inside the same AD domain and make sure you have set the right IE settings as below:

[image]

Comment: So it sounds like my goal really is not possible in a chrome or ff?

Comment: Chrome also use the IE's settings for windows authentication.